# Optimization issue for a javascript game

Tags: javascript, html, optimization, server, multiplayer

I'm currently working on a multiplayer game (in HTML5 & javascript) that involves all players starting in one area and progressing through area by area, one at a time, trying to reach the end (area #30). Note that players can join and play at any time.

Initially, I don't load any of the areas. When someone joins, I load the area they will enter by creating new objects (provided no one else is currently occupying that area). When someone leaves a certain area, I delete all objects in the area (once again, provided no one else if currently occupying that area). These objects are all stored in an object array.

My issue is this game takes up a lot of CPU and server power. Is there any way to optimize this process?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask